# What's a good word for "estimating the correctness"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Let's say you are given a set of numbers, called *the state*, and you are supposed to use external information to estimate if they are correct.

I am looking for a word that means "to estimate the quality/correctness of something".
I don't want to use "evaluate" because, in the context of numbers, it typically has another meaning, and "judge" seems too informal to me. "Verify" and "validate" would fit, but imply to much confidence in the result.

I want to say something like "I have ??? the state; it is correct" or "...; there might be a problem with X".

So far, my search turned up "assess" and "assay", but I don't know which would be better in this context.

Comment: Would _examine_ work?

Comment: The verb *assess* perfectly fits here. WordWeb mentions: Assess (v) Estimate or determine the nature, value, quality, ability, extent, or significance of. "I will have the jewels assessed by a professional"

Answer (score 5):

A couple of choices for you:

- You can ***corroborate*** the figures, to check their source and independently verify that they are reasonable.
- You can ***check*** the figures to do an analysis of the figures and ensure that they are correct.
- You can ***assess*** the figures in order to determine how good/useful the figures are.
- You can ***verify***, or even ***confirm*** the figures, if you just want to make sure they are correct.
- You can ***correct*** the figures if you know them to be incorrect and are going to compute better, more accurate ones to replace them with.
- You can ***double-check*** the figures if you are pretty sure they are right, but just want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: "Check" and "assess" are good general words. I'd add "test" and "evaluate". "Verify" and "confirm" imply that you think the numbers are correct and you are just making sure, which the poster said he doesn't want to convey. "Corroborate" means that you are comparing against another source, which may or may not be applicable in context.